# RestSharp JSON Not Deseralizing

Tags: c#, json, wcf, restsharp

I have a RESTful WCF Service function, however it is not serializing properly via the RestSharp Client.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestDragon
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "getconfig")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "getconfig/{id}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    DragonConfig GetConfig(string id);
}

public class RestDragon : IRestDragon
{
    public DragonConfig GetConfig(string id)
    {
        var config = new DragonConfig {Name = "Test", Data = "DAtaaaaaa"};
        return config;
    }
}
```

And here is how I consume the service:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.ReadLine();

    var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:5463/RESTDragon.svc");
    client.AddDefaultHeader("ContentType", "application/json");
    var request = new RestRequest("/getconfig/11123") {Method = Method.GET, RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};
    var response = client.Execute<DragonConfig>(request);
    Console.WriteLine("Response: " + response.Content);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

However it is returning:

```
Response: {"getconfigResult":{"Data":"DAtaaaaaa","Name":"Test"}}
```

I am unable to access the De-Serialized Data via response.Data.*. It comes back as null, and the data is shown in Content however, in the JSON Format, with the strange getconfigResult identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `response.Data` instead of `response.Content` to get the deserialized object.

Comment: The issue was BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped. Setting it to Bare resolved the issue.